# Is there any way to stop Visual Studio from removing empty spaces after Ctrl+E+D

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, code-formatting, auto-indent

I've got a view that has the following code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#General" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-home"></i> General</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Background" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-picture"></i> Background</a></li>
    <li><a href="#FormContainer" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Form Container</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Logo" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-picture"></i> Logo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Colors" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-tint"></i> Colors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Fonts" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-font"></i> Fonts</a></li>
</ul>
```

The classes and html attributes are from Twitter Bootstrap but that's not important.

After pressing Ctrl+E+D combination the following code gets changed:

`<i class="icon-home"></i> General` to `<i class="icon-home"></i>General`

I also tried putting an empty space between the `<i>` tags but it gets stripped out as well.

This is effectively moving the tab title closer to the icon and although it's easy to fix I don't want to have to do it every time I benefit from auto code formatting in Visual Studio.

Is there any way to change/tweak this behaviour?

Comment: This looks like it would be something that would be in the option menu  that would specify the spaces and different things and it is also done per language. Another option may be to try using `&nbsp;`

Comment: @kwelch I thought of using &nbsp; just after posting the question. It would work as a workaround.

Comment: I am glad you were able to find something that would work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with things here :: Tools/Options/Text Editor/HTML/Formatting

You'll find it a little arduous at times to get things exactly the way you want them, but if there's a way to adjust your spacing, that would be where it is located.

Comment: Thanks. I found it. I wasn't able to change the behaviour of removing spaces from inside the tag but I was able to configure the `<i>` tag to have a line break after the closing tag.